# How to pass in a SelectList and use associative select to get name from id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Given the following code how can I select a list item in my view to get the name via an id?  I just want to get the name value from the list via a local @id variable that maps to the lists id range.

This really has nothing to do with dropdowns...perhaps selectlist is the wrong container for associative look up dictionaries?

-- Controller

```
ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.TypeIds, "TypeId", "Name");
```

-- View

```
@* ??? Get the name by a local @id  *@
<div>ViewBag.TypeId.SelectItemNameById(@id)</div>  @* Bad psuedo code here... *@
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use Jquery with an ajax call on the `onChange` of your dropdownlist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#MyDrop").change(function () { GetValue("#MyDrop"); });
});

function GetValue(objSource) {
var url = '/Home/Index/GetValue/';
$.getJSON(url, { id: $(objSource).val() }, function (data) {       
      //with data returned fill your fields
    });
});
```

}

From the controller

```
public ActionResult GetValue(string id)
{
  int intId = 0;
  int.TryParse(id, out intId);
  var myData = //Get the value from Id
  return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Remeber to use `AllowGet` if you don't do a `Post` call from your ajax (like in my example)

**UPDATE to reflect the comments**

To achive what you need use a Dictionary passed via ViewBag.

Then from your view you access the (Dictionary)ViewBag.MyDictionary. 
Or whatever collection you prefer.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I just need to peel off that associated [id]=[name] value and I thought a list would be something simple to pass in that had associative 0(1) access like a dictionary/collection.  All I need to do is grab the the id and look it up in a list, selectlist or collection/Hash but really wasn't sure how to do it.  It really doesn't have anything to do with dropdownlists.

Comment: If understand correctly this time, I will use Dictionary<int, string> passed via ViewBag. Then from your view you access the (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewBag.MyDictionary. Or whatever colection you prefer.

Comment: Yes, this worked fine: db.TypesIds.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);  Thanks!