# How to fill a dropdown list dynamically in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a search application  in mvc3 where I have 2 tables :

**1.State:**`Id(pk)` and `state_name`

**2.District:**`Id(pk)`,`s_id(f.k.)`, `District_name`

I am using code first and EF and have database created for it called Search

I want my index to show all states in drop down list

following is my `State.cs` code

```
public partial class State
{
    public State()
    {
        this.Districts = new HashSet<District>();
        this.Search_master = new HashSet<Search_master>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }}
```

this is my `District` class:

```
 public partial class District
{
    public District()
    {
        this.Search_master = new HashSet<Search_master>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string District_name { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; } }
```

How can I call the data stored in my tables in my index page
thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery to bind to the onChange event of the State dropdown. And do an ajax call passing the stateId to the server that will return a json list with the correct districts.

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7631295/394028) for a sample

**Update**
on how to populate a dropdownlist [look here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/populating-drop-down-lists-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: :thnx for replying...bt i still didnt get that...can u help me...i updated my answer!

Comment: You should create a model with two SelectList. one fo state and one for district and int StateId and int DistrictId and bind them to soemthing like this: model.States = new SelectList(repository.GetStates(), "Id", "Name", model.StateId);

Comment: :Thnx.....bt i am getting an error in repository.GetStates().....do i need to create it? and if so, where shal i put in ...in the Viewmodel??

Comment: That was an example assuming you are using repository pattern. In any case that method should return an IEnumerable<T> or derivates. In the viewModel I will put the selectList and the Id in the viewmodel. I updated my answer with a link to a sample

Answer (score 0):

Pass the contents of the first dropdown in the model and use a

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyList)

Bind to the change event and send a jQuery ajax call to a server method you create in a controller. Pass the dynamic list back using JSON and parse the results. Manually add them to your dropdown.

Alternatively just do a full post back and send the second list back in the model, hiding the other dropdown while it has an empty result set.